# How to add resistor between two connections on breadboard

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to replicate a circuit-diagram for my Raspberry Pi and DHT temperature & humidity sensor. I noticed that the author of the tutorial added a resistor between two connections (see orange and purple on the left side). Unfortunately I have no idea what this would look like on a breadboard. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction/ resources? Any advice would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: investigate how a breadboard is constructed ......... http://secte1.elec.uow.edu.au/traininglab/Equipment/Breadboard.htm

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the link from the comments ([Breadboard](http://secte1.elec.uow.edu.au/traininglab/Equipment/Breadboard.htm)), place the resistor between the voltage line and the data connection line. This is a pull up resistor.

[image]

The above image shows a connection between the voltage line and ground. In your case the resistor should be between the voltage and data line.